# Will assigning a separate UA tracking ID make Google Analytics NOT exclude subdomain as referral source?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, universal-analytics

I (might) want to treat shop.example.com as a separate tracking entity from www.example.com with Universal Analytics. [Here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en), Google says

> Google Analytics automatically excludes the domain associated with a
>   property as a referral source, so you won’t see self-referrals in your
>   Analytics reports.

Will assigning a separate tracking ID to shop.example.com make GA treat it as a referral source to www.example.com, and vice versa?

(I do want blog.example.com, for example, to be excluded as a referral source.)

Answer (score 1):

No, the GA UA number does not define the uniqueness of the domain, it is set within the Google Analytics tracking tag automatically.

To force GA to view hits to your subdomain as a separate domain and pass referral source attributions as necessary, use ga('create') to push these customizations to the cookie.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#cookiesYum

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains